# How do I link to a div on page with ruby?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

My current code is:

```
= link_to 'Compare Schools', '#', class: 'btn-default'
```

I want to essentially link back to the top of the page. To do so in regular html I would link to a div at the top of the page (in this case div="header-wrapper"), which would make the code:

```
= link_to 'Compare Schools', '.section-wrapper', class: 'btn-default'
```

This however gives me an error message No route matches [GET] "/.section-wrapper" when I click on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that links need to be to separate pages, or within the page. If prefixed with the anchor indicator `#` it's presumed to be an anchor destination. Those are typically made like this:

```
%a{ name: 'anchor_name' }
```

Then you can link to this:

```
= link_to('Link', '#anchor_name')
```

If you try and link to a CSS selector, it's going to be interpreted as a relative URL and it won't work.